# Switch between div that will take up entire page in pure js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for a way to, with multiple `<div>` elements, have some functionality that can switch between the `<div>` as if they were pages. I want there to be an 'active' page, and when certain elements or `<a>` are clicked, there is a way to switch to another div that takes up the whole page. At any given time, only one such page-like `<div>` is visible.

I am aware this can be done in jquery, such as with their `data-role="page"` attribute for divs, but I am wondering how this can be done mechanically in pure javascript and css.

Here is an example I wrote, but it does not work, it only allows a transition once, then get stuck.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
       <title>Page Divs</title>
       <style>
     .uipage {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        border: 0;
      }
    
      .lightpage {
        background-color: #fcfbd1;
      }
    
      .darkpage {
        background-color: red;
      }
             
       </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div class="lightpage" id="pageone" name="pagetype">
      <p onclick="switchPages();">Hello! This is page one!</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="darkpage" id="pagetwo" name="pagetype">
      <p onclick="switchPages();">Hello! This is page two!</p>
    </div>
    
       <script>
         document.getElementById('pageone').style.top = 0;
         document.getElementById('pageone').style.left = 0;
         document.getElementById('pageone').style.width = '100%';
         document.getElementById('pageone').style['min-height'] = '100%';
         document.getElementById('pageone').style.position = 'absolute';
         document.getElementById('pageone').style.border = 0;
       </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var currentPage = 1;
      function switchPages() {
        if(currentPage === 1) {
         document.getElementById('pagetwo').style.top = 0;
         document.getElementById('pagetwo').style.left = 0;
         document.getElementById('pagetwo').style.width = '100%';
         document.getElementById('pagetwo').style['min-height'] = '100%';
         document.getElementById('pagetwo').style.position = 'absolute';
         document.getElementById('pagetwo').style.border = 0;
         currentPage = 2;
        } else if(currentPage === 2) {
         document.getElementById('pageone').style.top = 0;
         document.getElementById('pageone').style.left = 0;
         document.getElementById('pageone').style.width = '100%';
         document.getElementById('pageone').style['min-height'] = '100%';
         document.getElementById('pageone').style.position = 'absolute';
         document.getElementById('pageone').style.border = 0;
         currentPage = 1;      
        }
      }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Basically there is a transition to page two, but then it will not work after that. I am not sure if dynamically changing the style object is a good approach here or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that you're only applying the styles to the `<div>` you're trying to show but you're not actually hiding the other one.
Have you tried applying `display: none;` to the div you're meaning to hide?
I would apply the desired styles for the div assuming it's visible and just changing the `display` mode from `none` to `block` or viceversa depending on the one clicked

Answer (score 1):

Several things going on. 
First, you should avoid styles as much as you can. Instead, use classes, they run better and you can reuse the classes. Then you can just use

```
document.getElementById('pageone').addClass('selected');
document.getElementById('pagetwo').removeClass('selected');
```

Second, You are adding styles to the target id, but you are not removing the styles to the id/ids that you don't want in front.

I know you want pure js, but you also may want to look up jquery. It can make things like this a lot easier with simple commands like

```
$('#pageone').show(); 
$('#pagetwo').hide();
```